# Possible to do incremental training with AWS comprehend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp, amazon-comprehend, active-learning

I am looking at AWS Comprehend for a text classification task which will involve an active learning component. I am trying to understand if it's possible to incrementally train a custom comprehend model using batches of newly annotated data, or if it only supports training from scratch. In this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/active-learning-workflow-for-amazon-comprehend-custom-classification-part-2/) it sounds like they are stitching the annotated data back together with the original training data (i.e. retraining from screatch each time), but I don't see the mentioned cloudformation template (part 1 has the template for training/deployment, but part 2 seems to be talking about another template).

Is it possible to do incremental training with Comprehend? Or would I need to use a custom text classification model through SageMaker and then do incremental training that way? I am attempting to do the following

1. Get a pretrained model
2. Fine tune on own classification data
3. Incrementally train on annotated low confidence preditions

1 and 2 can be done with AWS Comprehend, but not sure about 3. Thanks